A Lebanese-Israeli drama movie about a woman searching her son
I'm looking for a 2007-2013 made Lebanese-Israeli movie that a middle aged woman searching her son at the border between these countries. The language was Arabic. The time in the movie could be earlier than that like late 70's or 80's. There was some scenes that the war and exploding bombs, injured and dead people etc. There were also some images about her son which is 8-10 year old. She was brunette with black hair, black eye brows, black eyes, in her 40's. 
She took a cab and wanted to go to the conflict area. The Israeli army was attacking the area and it was too dangerous to go there. The cab driver asked why and she replied in a evasive way. He said that it was too risky and wanted more money than it has to be. He was short, about 35 ages, short black hair and had light beard. She accepted and gave the money. She was so upset and careless about her clothes. The cab driver was taking a peek by the rear view mirror constantly. She noticed that and covered her up. 
There were no open gas stations on the road and they bought gas from some people in the jerry cans. When the night they stayed at a house, which belongs to some relative of the cab driver. She cried a lot but he cheered her up. The 2nd day they were to close to the border. Israeli army was patrolling. He said that it was too dangerous to go further. She denied it and wanted to go on her own. 
He catched her before the Israeli army and got her to his car. The road wasn't suitable for the cab, there were lots of rocks and stones on the road. But somehow they passed the soldiers and went further. 
I couldn't remember the rest. By the way there was a scene that they made love  in a house but also couldn't remember it when and where. 

Sounds like Sous les bombes (2007)
From Wikipedia

Although she grew up in Lebanon, wealthy Lebanese Muslim Zeina Nasrueddi (Nada Abu Farhat) has been living in Dubai with her architect husband and son, Karim. Marital difficulties led her to send her son to spend the summer with her sister Maha in Lebanon. When the 2006 Lebanon War began she traveled to Beirut via Turkey. In order to find her son, she hires Lebanese Christian taxi driver Tony (Georges Khabbaz) to drive her to Southern Lebanon. In their search for Maha and Karim, they encounter the devastation wrought by the war and learn each other's personal secrets, including the fact that Tony's brother was a member of the South Lebanon Army and is now living in exile in Israel.


Yes that's it. Thanks for your quick reply.
